# When is a Moishezon manifold rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

We  talk about the question only on  complex manifold category.

A variety $Y$ is called **rational** if it is birationally equivalent to $\mathbf{P}^{n}$ for some $n$. Moishezon manifolds have many equivalent definitions. Here we use a well known one,  characterizing  **Moishezon manifolds** as manifolds which are bimeromorphic to projective algebraic varieties.

**Question**: When is a Moishezon manifold rational? If there is no a general answer, how about for a low-dimensional  Moishezon manifold? Any comment and answer is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer for dimension $3$:

By Theorem 3 of [Timmerscheidt's article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01450682), a three dimensional complex manifold $X$ is rational if and only if $X$ is Moishezon, ruled, $H^1(X,\mathbb Q) = 0$ and $H^2(X,\mathbb Q)$ is generated by the cohomology classes of ruled surfaces contained in $X$.